# OpenCV estimateAffine3D failes with cryptic error message

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have 2 3D point clouds, stored in numpy.ndarrays, containing either 0 or 1 (Indication of a detected point or none).
I would like to compute the affine transformation that converts the 'Test' array to the 'Reference' array.

I call the function like this:

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import estimateAffine3D

[...] Read in the Arrays [...]

print(np.shape(Reference))
print(np.shape(Test))

AffineTransfMatrix = estimateAffine3D(Reference,Test)
```

And the Output I get is:

```
(132, 2055, 701)
(132, 2055, 701)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (count >= 0 && to.checkVector(3) == count) in estimateAffine3D, file /home/wenzlern/libraries/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp, line 513
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wenzlern/code/python/AbsorbtionSpecAnalysis/AlignEnergies.py", line 67, in <module>
    estimateAffine3D(Reference,Test)
cv2.error: /home/wenzlern/libraries/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/ptsetreg.cpp:513: error: (-215) count >= 0 && to.checkVector(3) == count in function estimateAffine3D
```

I have tried playing around with the data type, using Reference/Test.astype('float32'), but could not change the result. The documentation does not seem to specify a specific format.(http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#estimateaffine3d).

Does anyone have an idea what could go wrong? Am I missing something, or calling the function wrong?

Thanks a lot,
Nils

Comment: so you have some kind of voxel grid, or a set of point coordinates? `estimateAffine3D` needs point positions as input (x,y,z coordinates). I don't know what kind of elements this are in python, but you would need cv::Point3f in C++.

Comment: Basically I just have the ndarray. There is no spatial information/grid/voxelsize. I have been looking into using Points/coordinates. But in the Python bindings the 'Point' class seems to be missing. On the few related issues that I found ppl use tuples to represent the coordinates. However, I have no idea how I should format my array to represent this information as well.

Comment: I'm confused about the "containing either 0 or 1" ... I understood it the way that if there is a 1 in array position [10,25,13] the it would mean there is a point with position (10,25,13). This would mean that you in fact have some kind of voxel grid (a dense space of information)?!? If I misunderstood, can you further explain what kind of data you have (maybe a small example)? I don't know numpy or openCV for python...

Comment: probably you'll need a Nx3 matrix with 1. column = x coordinate; 2. column = y coordinate and 3. column = z coordinate of active points.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I think to understand now that the estimateAffine3D does not understand that the indices are the position as it just sees an array...

Comment: Background: I have two 3D images (Xray-Tomograms) that I threshold and mask to single out the particles. Wherever a particle (or part of one) is detected the mask is 1, else 0 ('Binarization' of the image). As I now need to align the images I would like to compute the affine transformation to warp the test point cloud to the reference. Is there anywhere a documentation about this cv2 class that specifies in what format the function expects it's data specific for python?

Comment: can you just try to create a Nx3 array with sample x,y,z coordinates and call the function with same source and destination Nx3 matrix? If that works you can just loop your ndarray over variables i,j,k and if array[i,j,k] == 1 you add a row to a Nx3 array with values row = (i,j,k).

Answer (score 2):

I've found that, with OpenCV 4.1.1, handing a numpy array **with dtype that isn't np.int64** will also give a similar error message for estimateAffinePartial2D and estimateAffine2D:
`error: (-215:Assertion failed) count >= 0 && to.checkVector(2) == count in function 'estimateAffinePartial2D'`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question?

Comment: Correct, it does not, I found no SO question for this error with  estimateAffinePartial2D or estimateAffine2D but google leads here. Feel free to flag if this is not proper SO.

Comment: no worries. not sure what the protocol is but might make more sense to be a comment?

Comment: I also discovered that sets of points have to be of type np.int64. It was not clear from the error message and it took me quite a while before I get it working.

Comment: +1 for numpy array having `int` type for `estimateAffine2D`.  Note the similar `findHomography` function wants `float32` as input `dtype`.

Answer (score 1):

User Micka (in the comments to the question) had the right solution. The Array has to be passed in Nx3 format.
In other words:
The coordinates (x,y,z) of every point in the Point-Cloud are one 1x3 entry in the Nx3 matrix to be passed.

Thanks!